# What's the partial derivative of inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $ f = \langle u,Ax \rangle $, where $A$ is a $n$-by-$m$ matrix and $u$ and $x$ are vectors with appropriate dimentions. What's the partial derivatives of function $f$ with respect to $x$ and $u$ ?

Comment: welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using differential yields
$$
df=
\mathbf{Ax}:d\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{u}:\mathbf{A} d\mathbf{x}
$$
The derivatives are
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}=\mathbf{Ax}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{u}
$$